# how to find specific items in a list and do things with that item

Tags: python, list, input

I'm very at python and have no idea how to properly ask this question, so here goes.

i'm trying to get a user input, and use that to find an item in a list, then have that item do something... and i'm not sure how to do that.

sort of like this:

```
things = ['thing1','thing2','thing3']
item = input('type your item here')
if item in things == True:
    if item == 'thing1':
        do something
    elif item == 'thing2':
        do something else
    elif item == 'thing 3':
        do something different
```

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you actually **tried** your code? If so, what happened, and how did that differ from your expectations? And if not, why not?!

Comment: you are missing a closing quote on line `elif item == 'thing 3:` should be elif item == 'thing 3':

Comment: I don't know if this will answer your question, but there is a bug in your code which prevents all other if statements to be executed. Look at the third line `if item in things == True:` it should be `if item in things:`

Comment: Sorry guys, this was something I just typed up to give you an example if what I was trying to do. In trying to have the user input a value, and match that to an item in a list, and depending on the item that they choose, it does something different. Like I said, I'm really new at this whole thing, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary, with the string as key, and the function as value:

```
todos = {
  'thing1': do_something,
  'thing2': do_something_else,
  'thing3': do_something_different,
}

item = input('type your item here')
todos.get(item, lambda: None)()
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think you should use a filter to extract an array of only the items in the array you want to "do something" then use a for expression to "do something" with each element in the new array

```html
//in this example I use filter to select all the even numbers in the
//list and compute their square

//here is a list of numbers
array = [1,2,4,5,7]

//use a filter to take only the elements from the list you need
//the elements part of the new array, arrEvens, will be all the
//elements of array that return true in the lambda expression
arrEvens = filter(lambda a : a%2 ==0, array)

//do something (in this case print the square) of all the 
//numbers in the new list of elements that passed the filtering
//test
for x in arrEvens:
  print(x*x)
```

Hope I understood your question correctly and this helps.

Comment: I didn't think of using a filter, it could work if I'm understanding how to use it properly. In my case, it might not be the best option where I only ever want to pick it one item in my list, which is whatever the user inputs, and have that item do something. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: hmm does the value have to be picked from the array? Could you simply do something with the value when the user enters it and update the array separately?

Comment: That's a very good point, I was thinking if I wanted to add in more options later it would be easier to update, but upon reflection I don't think it would be... Well, at least I learned something new! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Daniel said correct , to use dictionary for todos,
well in case if you have functions that you want to perform for that matches
you can try this:

```
todos = { 'thing1': function1,
          'thing2': function2,
          'thing3': function3 }
def function1():
    """any operation """
    pass
def function2():
    """any operation """
    pass
def function3():
    """ any operation """
    pass

input_val = raw_input("Enter the thing to do")
todos[input_val]()
```

hope it helps,

Comment: I totally didn't realize you could put functions in a dictionary. I think that'll solve my problem, thanks Daniel and jazz,